# Trying to mmap() file in windows throws PermissionError: [WinError 5] even if I write the file

Tags: python, windows, mmap

I am just trying to `mmap()` a file in windows using Python but it throws `PermissionError: [WinError 5]` every time.

I've just written this minimal example that replicates this behavior.

```py
import mmap
import pickle
import random

print("Generate 1 million k/v data points")

garbage = { f'key_{x}_{random.uniform(1000,9999)}': random.uniform(1,9999999) for x in range(1000_000) }

print("Picking that garbage")

with open('test.pickle','wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(garbage, fp)

print("Now trying to mmap the file...")

with open('test.pickle','rb') as fp:
    mapped = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0)

print('Not reached. The line above throws PermissionError: [WinError 5] Permission Denied')
```

How to get rid of that nasty `Permission Error: [WinError 5]` ?

Since I am the one writing the file, there should be no permission issues, right?

Answer (score 4):

Turn outs the problem is in the `mmap.mmap()` call.

To fix the error, just add `access=mmap.ACCESS_READ` to match the mode you open() the file.

```
 mapped = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
```

By default it tries to map the file with *write* permissions, but was opening it in read-only mode.